# AWS S3 How to read a .gz object without downloading PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My S3 contains .gz objects that contain JSON within. I simply want to access this JSON without actually downloading objects to a file.

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    $object = $object['Key'];

    $result = $client->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $object
    ));

    echo $result['Body'] . "\n";
}
```

When I run the above in the shell it outputs gibberish on the `echo` line. What's the correct way to simply retrieve the contents of the .gz object and save to a variable?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stream wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-stream-wrapper.html?highlight=stream) like this.

```
$client->registerStreamWrapper();

if ($stream = fopen('s3://bucket/key.gz', 'r')) {
    // While the stream is still open
    while (!feof($stream)) {
        // Read 1024 bytes from the stream
        $d = fread($stream, 1024);
        echo zlib_decode($d);
    }
    // Be sure to close the stream resource when you're done with it
    fclose($stream);
}
```

If you are sending it to a browser you dont need to zlib_decode it, just set a header:

```
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly. I encountered errors on some objects but increasing the number of bytes solved it.